# Error in string method substring in java

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am getting this error in this code. What should I do?

//error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
at StringExample.main(StringExample.java:18)
```

//code

```
String s=sc.nextLine();
int first=s.indexOf("");
int second=s.lastIndexOf("");
String sur=s.substring(second+1);      //18 line
String middle=s.substring(first+1,second);
String firstname=s.substring(0,first);
System.out.println(sur+""+firstname+""+middle);
```

Comment: Please make sure that `second+1` is less than length of string `s`.

Comment: what String does `sc.nextLine()` return?

Comment: `indexOf("")` returns the start of the string and  `lastIndexOf("")` returns the end of the string. I assume you want to split get ` `. Therefore use `indexOf(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `second` in your code is most likely the last index of your string. For `hello world` it would be 11.

Now if you increment that number and use it as the first index of the string, you get `-1`, because your starting index is greater than the last index in your string.

Logically, it doesn't make sense either. You try to get a substring from a string which starts after the actual string.

Looking at your example, I think you should use `indexOf(" ")` instead. It gives you the index of a space instead.

Answer (score 0):

.indexOf("") method give you start of your string and .lastIndexOf("") give you end of your string..I think you should use your last index method(".lastIndexOf("")) like .lastIndexOf(" ");.